# ASP.NET: Reusing the same Repeater ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, refactoring, repeater, dry

I'm currently using a certain `ItemTemplate` for three repeaters that are all on the same page, but they are all bound to different data sources. Is there any way to refactor my web form *without* using a user control to easily refer to this template so I will only have to define it once?

Comment: If the template is defined in the markup, it will get dirty if other controls should refer to the same template defined earlier.

A user control is clean and would be my choice in this scenario. Any reason why you don't want a control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it's possible, create another asp.net control (ascx) that is having a repeater, create a public method that accepts data table (or list or items) and bind the repeater with that, you will probably get this done in 10mins

```
public void BindData(DataTable dt)
{
    rpt.DataSource = dt;
    rpt.DataBind();
}
```

It will work if your dt has same column names.

Answer (score 3):

No. That's the reason user controls exist, to encapsulate repeating visual components.

Comment: I don't quite agree. To me, user controls are their own "entities" which can be put just about anywhere and hold their own state, etc. What I was looking for was something similar to a macro.